# Docker desktop - compose - file permissions issues when running bind volumes in Ubuntu for local development. permissions denied error

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am having an issue when running Docker Compose using Docker Desktop for local development with two services in Ubuntu. I am mounting the current directory with the source code as a volume inside the container. I am running debug mode inside the container. I want to make changes in my host, have the volume sync with the container, and run it inside the container.

This issue is that in Linux, when Docker Desktop copies files from the host to the container (bind volume), it remaps the user and group ids. The id of 0 (root) inside the container will be mapped to the host user (in my case, 1000). See 
https://docs.docker.com/desktop/faqs/linuxfaqs/#how-do-i-enable-file-sharing

My Docker container API runs using a non-root user with an id of 1000 (inside the container). Since the ids of files from the host synced inside the container by the volume mount are not matching those of the user that runs inside the container, I am running into **EACCES: permission denied**.

docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: '3.8'

services:
  api:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        - APP_PORT=${APP_PORT:-3000}
      # Only build development stage from Dockerfile
      target: development
    container_name: api-app
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
    networks:
      - appnetwork
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    env_file:
      - .env
    # Run in debug mode: npm run start:debug
    # Run in dev mode: npm run start:dev
    command: npm run start:debug
    ports:
      - ${APP_PORT}:${APP_PORT}
      - 9229:9229
    restart: unless-stopped

  postgres:
    image: postgres:15.2
    container_name: postgres-app
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: ${DB_USERNAME}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
      POSTGRES_DB: ${DB_NAME}
      TZ: ${TZ}
    networks:
      - appnetwork
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - 5432:5432

networks:
  appnetwork:
    name: shared-app-network
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  db-data:
    driver: local
```

Dockerfile

```yaml
ARG IMAGE=nikolaik/python-nodejs:python3.11-nodejs18-slim

FROM $IMAGE AS base
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
RUN chown -R pn:pn /usr/src/app && chmod -R 700 /usr/src/app
ENV TZ="America/New_York"
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

FROM base AS development

USER pn

COPY --chown=pn:pn package*.json ./
COPY --chown=pn:pn python/* python/

RUN npm install
RUN pip install -r python/requirements.txt

COPY --chown=pn:pn . .

RUN npm run build

CMD [ "node", "dist/main" ]

## PRODUCTION 

FROM base AS production 
ARG APP_PORT=$APP_PORT

ARG NODE_ENV=production
ENV NODE_ENV=$NODE_ENV

USER pn

COPY --chown=pn:pn package*.json ./
COPY --chown=pn:pn python/* python/

RUN npm install
RUN pip install -r python/requirements.txt 

COPY --from=development /usr/src/app/dist dist/

EXPOSE ${APP_PORT}

CMD [ "node", "dist/main" ]
```

screenshot ls -la command output [my api container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yehnw.png)

Can somebody tell me how to fix this?

I have tried so many ways to fix it, such as setting the container user id inside the container in the dockerfile to 1000, which is my host user id, but it does not work. I tried all the ways listed in https://jtreminio.com/blog/running-docker-containers-as-current-host-user/ but to no avail. I tried creating the image from scratch using a python:3.11.3-bullseye image, then creating the user and group, but the same issue

I have the latest version of Docker Compose. The app is a Nest.js app. I also have some Python code running, which is why I chose the nikolaik/python-nodejs:python3.11-nodejs18-slim image.

Error message in container

```bash
api-app       | 
api-app       | error TS5033: Could not write file '/usr/src/app/dist/utils/utils.js.map': EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/src/app/dist'.
api-app       | 
api-app       | error TS5033: Could not write file '/usr/src/app/dist/utils/xl-parser.d.ts': EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/src/app/dist'.
api-app       | 
api-app       | error TS5033: Could not write file '/usr/src/app/dist/utils/xl-parser.js': EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/src/app/dist'.
api-app       | 
api-app       | error TS5033: Could not write file '/usr/src/app/dist/utils/xl-parser.js.map': EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/src/app/dist'.
```

ls -la output in container

```bash
$ ls -la
total 832
drwxrwxr-x   8 root root   4096 May 10 13:42 .
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root   4096 May  9 20:22 ..
-rw-rw-r--   1 root root     92 May  9 20:27 .dockerignore
-rw-rw-r--   1 root root    299 May  9 23:16 .env
-rw-rw-r--   1 root root    199 May  9 20:27 .env.sample
-rw-rw-r--   1 root root    788 May  9 20:27 .eslintrc.js
drwxrwxr-x   8 root root   4096 May 10 13:33 .git
-rw-rw-r--   1 root root    522 May  9 20:27 .gitignore
-rw-rw-r--   1 root root     60 May  9 20:27 .prettierrc
drwxrwxr-x   2 root root   4096 May  9 20:27 .vscode
-rw-rw-r--   1 root root    864 May 10 20:53 Dockerfile
-rw-rw-r--   1 root root   2017 May 10 00:00 Dockerfile.dev
-rw-rw-r--   1 root root   1063 May  9 20:27 LICENSE
-rw-rw-r--   1 root root    839 May  9 20:27 README.md
-rw-rw-r--   1 root root   1107 May 10 00:02 docker-compose.yml
-rw-rw-r--   1 root root    483 May 10 13:42 dockercntct.txt
-rw-rw-r--   1 root root   2412 May 10 13:41 dockerinfo.txt
-rw-rw-r--   1 root root    179 May  9 20:27 nest-cli.json
drwxr-xr-x 591 pn   pn    20480 May 10 20:54 node_modules
-rw-rw-r--   1 root root 725053 May  9 20:27 package-lock.json
-rw-rw-r--   1 root root   3418 May  9 20:27 package.json
drwxrwxr-x   2 root root   4096 May  9 20:27 python
drwxrwxr-x  22 root root   4096 May  9 20:27 src
drwxrwxr-x   2 root root   4096 May  9 20:27 test
-rw-rw-r--   1 root root    101 May  9 20:27 tsconfig.build.json
-rw-rw-r--   1 root root    629 May  9 20:27 tsconfig.json
```

ls -lan output in container

```bash
$ ls -lan 
total 832
drwxrwxr-x   8    0    0   4096 May 10 13:42 .
drwxr-xr-x   1    0    0   4096 May  9 20:22 ..
-rw-rw-r--   1    0    0     92 May  9 20:27 .dockerignore
-rw-rw-r--   1    0    0    299 May  9 23:16 .env
-rw-rw-r--   1    0    0    199 May  9 20:27 .env.sample
-rw-rw-r--   1    0    0    788 May  9 20:27 .eslintrc.js
drwxrwxr-x   8    0    0   4096 May 10 13:33 .git
-rw-rw-r--   1    0    0    522 May  9 20:27 .gitignore
-rw-rw-r--   1    0    0     60 May  9 20:27 .prettierrc
drwxrwxr-x   2    0    0   4096 May  9 20:27 .vscode
-rw-rw-r--   1    0    0    864 May 10 20:53 Dockerfile
-rw-rw-r--   1    0    0   2017 May 10 00:00 Dockerfile.dev
-rw-rw-r--   1    0    0   1063 May  9 20:27 LICENSE
-rw-rw-r--   1    0    0    839 May  9 20:27 README.md
-rw-rw-r--   1    0    0   1107 May 10 00:02 docker-compose.yml
-rw-rw-r--   1    0    0    483 May 10 13:42 dockercntct.txt
-rw-rw-r--   1    0    0   2412 May 10 13:41 dockerinfo.txt
-rw-rw-r--   1    0    0    179 May  9 20:27 nest-cli.json
drwxr-xr-x 591 1000 1000  20480 May 10 20:54 node_modules
-rw-rw-r--   1    0    0 725053 May  9 20:27 package-lock.json
-rw-rw-r--   1    0    0   3418 May  9 20:27 package.json
drwxrwxr-x   2    0    0   4096 May  9 20:27 python
drwxrwxr-x  22    0    0   4096 May  9 20:27 src
drwxrwxr-x   2    0    0   4096 May  9 20:27 test
-rw-rw-r--   1    0    0    101 May  9 20:27 tsconfig.build.json
-rw-rw-r--   1    0    0    629 May  9 20:27 tsconfig.json
```

Comment: Can you `sudo apt-get install nodejs` to get a local Node interpreter for day-to-day development?  Your Ubuntu system will already have Python preinstalled.

Comment: Thanks for the input. But, This is a project which will be worked on by multiple developers, so if I can get docker compose working it would be great. If I run it in my Ubuntu machine, I will have to get postgres running as well locally.

Comment: You can use Docker for the database and point a non-Docker Node at it; this combination works well for being able to trivially destroy the database but still having the simplicity of an actually-local development environment.  It's also a single command to `apt-get install postgresql-server`.

Comment: Good suggestion. I was hoping to run local development using this guide Docker guide at https://docs.docker.com/language/nodejs/develop/#use-compose-to-develop-locally. 

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Can you add the detailed error message and the `ls -la` output as text in the question? I suspect you need to use `COPY chown=pn:pn...` when you are copying your application files if you want them to be owned by other than `root`

Comment: Let me run it again and add the details you requested. We cannot use COPY though as this is a volume bind done from current folder to inside the container.

Answer (score 0):

The [COPY](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy) command uses root by default:

> All new files and directories are created with a UID and GID of 0

This includes `COPY --from` statements. This is why you can see your `node_modules` director is correctly created with the `pn:pn` permissions, however files copied via the command `COPY --from=development /usr/src/app/dist dist/` will not copy the permissions.

As such you can remove most or all of the previous `chown` instructions. The only one that matters is when the files are copied into the final stage:

```
COPY --chown=pn:pn --from=development /usr/src/app/dist dist/
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I tried it and it does not work. In the docker compose file, I am setting the target as development, and the ```COPY --from=development``` is in the production stage.  So when I run ```docker compose up``` it runs the development stage and doesnot reach the production stage of the docker file build. I have added the error message and ls output in the question.

Comment: @SanthoshSasidharan In your `development` stage you do not need to drop privileges. Simply run the stage as `USER root` and remove all chown references to use `pn`. The only security implications for dropping privileges is when you are running node at the end of the last stage with `CMD`

Comment: Right. That is a good idea. In that case, I will be running node command as root user.  However, isn't that going against the idea of keeping development and production environment the same.

Comment: @SanthoshSasidharan These aren't "environments", they are stages in a multi-stage Docker build. The first stage "development" in this case just installs build tools required to build your project--`tsc`. `webpack`, etc. The next stage then discards those layers entirely and takes only the output from `npm build` and sets up a new image without those build tools. They are not environments. It might be easier to understand if you name the first stage e.g. "build" and the second stage "deploy".

Comment: I guess this is a good workaround.